# PHP- Session lost upon refresh or revist

Tags: php, html, session, refresh

I'm new to php as you can tell and I'm having trouble with my session.Session is being lost upon refreshing page. I have a simple button that toggles between light and dark mode, it works and I store the value into a session value. I'm able to print the value and see that it is being stored, however upon a refresh or a revisit, the mode switches to the opposite mode and then upon refresh/revisit, the state is actually saved. I've tried to search for my issue but I cant find anything and I'm off to bed so I thought I may as well post in the meantime. I'm not sure what I'm missing, probably something obvious, but I appreciate the help. I can only use PHP for this by the way.

```
<?php
session_start();
//header('Refresh: 3000; url=index.php');
echo "" . $_SESSION['color'] . "";
    
    echo "<body style = 'background-color: " . $_SESSION['color'] . ";'>";
  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>
        Web Technologies
    </title>
</head>

<body>

<?php session_start();

include_once "templateFunctions.php";

if (isset($_POST['dark'])) {
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['color'])) {
        //session_register('color');
        $_SESSION['color'] = "rgb(54, 53, 53)";
        echo "<body style = 'background-color: " . $_SESSION['color'] . ";'>";
        
    } else {
        
        if ($_SESSION['color'] == "rgb(54, 53, 53)") {
            $_SESSION['color'] = "white";
            echo "<body style = 'background-color: " . $_SESSION['color'] . ";'>";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['color'] = "rgb(54, 53, 53)";
            echo "<body style = 'background-color: " . $_SESSION['color'] . ";'>";
        }  
    }
}

/*$color = "rgb(48, 48, 48)";
    
setcookie('color', $color, time() + 10, '/');
$_COOKIE['color'] = [$color];
echo "<p>'$cookie'</p>";
echo "<body style = 'background-color: $cookie;'>";

else {
$_SESSION['color'] = "rgb(54, 53, 53)";

echo "<body style = 'background-color: " . $_SESSION['color'] . ";'>";

}
*/


?>
<div class = "header">
    <div class = "title" >
        <h1>Jimbo Fimbo</h1><h2><u>Software Stuff</u></h2></th>    
    </div>

    <div class = "img">
        <img id = "img1" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTci5Mqm2mgMe_9KfJR0TqMEd-A_wtmqq69cru0wed7OEQF6jVAYycqCY_KzWV0o3hIVYs&usqp=CAU" alt="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KEkrWRHCDQU/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
    
    
<hr style = "margin-bottom: 20px;">
<div class = "colgroup">
    <div class="column1">
        <h3 style = "text-align: center;">Menu</h3><hr style = "color:white;">
        <ul style = "padding-left:20px; font-size: 25px;">
            <li><a href="https://github.com">GitHub<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="courses.html">Courses<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">School<br></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
        
    <div class="column2">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        
        <img id = "img2"src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KEkrWRHCDQU/maxresdefault.jpg">
        <p> 
             Heres some lorem ipsum! <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Reprehenderit sunt est quia 
            necessitatibus est eius quis. Est dolor adipisci et dolor molestiae hic vitae expedita eum inventore quam aut mollitia natus. Qui quia 
            dolor aut totam Quis qui expedita repudiandae non quam magni et enim ipsa qui consequatur omnis. Ea incidunt debitis est nemo nesciunt 
            eum quia rerum eum recusandae sunt nam maiores saepe. Hic omnis dolores ab deserunt vero cum fugiat explicabo vel perferendis numquam. 
            Sed unde voluptatibus quo aliquid iure rem accusamus voluptatum aut maxime adipisci id molestiae voluptatem? In quia necessitatibus et 
            provident id nobis eius ea enim voluptatem in aliquam voluptas ut similique facilis. Et porro ipsam eos excepturi voluptatem non ullam sint. 
         </p>
         <p>Stuff goes here </p>
        
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="column3">
        <p style = "text-align: center;">Enrolled Courses</p>
        <hr style = "color:white;">
        <ol style = "padding-left: 20px; font-size: 25px;">
            <li>CS-3753</li>
            <li>CS-4393</li>
            <li>CS-4413</li>
            <li>CS-4423</li>
            <li>CS-4843</li>
        </ol>

        <form action="index.php" method = "post" accept-charset=utf-8 >
            <input type="submit" name = "dark" id ="submit" value = "Dark Mode">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="foot">
Copyright 2022, Jimbo Fimbo
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting what I mentioned above.
I've looked over the code to no avail, I've tried using another session variable to save the color change, I tried saving the session to a path using said method, and I've looked on the internet for similar problems but I guess I suck at googling since this seems like it would be straightforward.

Comment: When you refresh the page (after submission of the POST data), the script will enter your two if-then-else blocks (nested in your case) which most likely resets your session variable known as $_SESSION['color']

Comment: Your page may well be getting a HTML confused. You have multiple `<body>` elements being emitted. One before the `DOCTYPE` one hard coded after the `<head>` and then another attempt in the PHP code

Comment: You are also starting the session more than once

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also you are not setting the mode unless `if (isset($_POST['dark'])) {` So the first tike the script loads (and the form has not yet been submitted) you will not do the code inside that IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the problem that the session variable will be "toggled" on page refresh, One of the ways is to separate the change color part from your display part, so the form submission target can be set to "changecolor.php", which will trigger a page redirection to index.php upon changing the session variable :

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

/// initalize the color to be white if no color session variable
if (!isset($_SESSION['color'])) {
  $_SESSION['color'] = "white";
}

echo "<body style = 'background-color: " . $_SESSION['color'] . ";'>";

?>
/// other HTML code

<form action="changecolor.php" method = "post" accept-charset=utf-8 >
   <input type="submit" name = "dark" id ="submit" value = "Change Color Mode">
</form>
```

**changecolor.php**

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_POST['dark'])) {
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['color'])) {
        $_SESSION['color'] = "rgb(54, 53, 53)";
        
    } else {
        
        if ($_SESSION['color'] == "rgb(54, 53, 53)") {
            $_SESSION['color'] = "white";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['color'] = "rgb(54, 53, 53)";
        }
        
    }

header("Location: index.php");

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now the background color isnt changing. However the state is being saved since upon refresh/revisit the echo statement still outputs the same color. Edit: Nevermind I got it, just neeeded to actually update the color in the index.php.

Comment: Slightly changed the code , it works now : please see the sandbox [here](http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/suba/index.php)